# How to get UIButton name in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton, pin-code

I am currently making a `pin-code`. I want to incorporate all the functions into one function, in order to integrate the button event function into one So I want to get the name of `UIButton`, but I don't know how.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var oneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twoButton: UIButton!
...
var pinCodeNum : String! = ""
...

  @IBAction func OneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        pincodeLogic(sender)
    }

    func pincodeLogic(_ sender: UIButton) {
         // I want get value is (example : 'oneButton' or 'twoButton' or 'threeButton' more )
    }
```

As you can see from my code, I'm getting a '`sender`' as a parameter I want to know the name of `oneButton` or `twoButton` using this parameter. How do I know?

[image: screen]

My number button consists of a `button` and a `label`.

---

**EDit**

---

```swift
  @IBAction func OneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        pincodeLogic(sender)
    }

    func pincodeLogic(_ sender: UIButton) {
         if let number = sender.currentTitle {
            print(number)
        }
    }
```

I can't see the print log.

Comment: use `if let number =  sender.currentTitle { print(number)}`

Comment: Add a different function for each button.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister What do you mean by adding different functions to each button?

Comment: create the common method for each button and get directly sender.currentTitle using touchup action.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik is right, you should use `sender.currentTitle`

Comment: Hi @Anbu.Karthik I can't see the print log when I click one Button, Please look at the modified question.

Comment: Hi  @SagarChauhan  I can't see the print log when I click one Button, Please look at the modified question.

Comment: @iosbegindevel, `My number button consists of a button and a label.` What that means ?

Comment: @iosbegindevel you have 10 buttons. So have ten functions `@IBAction buttonOnePressed() {}` etc...

Comment: Ah ~ @Fogmeister I understand what you mean. I know I have to make ten of them. I just want to use a function as a function in a function. Is it impossible for me to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Even with ten functions you can call out to a single function that does the logic. `addNumberToPin(1)` etc...

Comment: @SagarChauhan The circle is the button and the number is the label.

Comment: @iosbegindevel, that's why `sender.currentTitle` is not work for you, because button haven't a title.

Comment: @SagarChauhan My button is an image, can I put in a number? I didn't know it, so I had to use the label uncomfortably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the sender with your button instances.

```
func pincodeLogic(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender {
    case oneButton:
        print("oneButton pressed")
    case twoButton:
        print("twoButton pressed")
    default:
        print("unknown button pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: The sender I receive is not a string.

Comment: @iosbegindevel I know. I've you can compare UIButton objects

Comment: It's the way I want it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the button action to perform some specific task.Just put a tag with your each button and add the same target to all.

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
switch sender.tag {
case 1:
    print("oneButton pressed")
case 2:
    print("twoButton pressed")
default:
    print("unknown button pressed")
 }
}
```

If you need just to print the button title the do the following.

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print(sender.titleLabel?.text! as! String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of the label present in the button using the sender, this is an example:

```
@IBAction func OneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
}
```

so you could do this:

```
@IBAction func OneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        pincodeLogic(sender)
  }

  func pincodeLogic(_ sender: UIButton) {
         if let number = sender.titleLabel?.text {
            print(number)
        }
  }
```

I hope I've been there for you. Let me know.

Comment: it also  I can't see the print log when I click one Button,

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: UIButton{
    print(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.